# MD5 of official Ubuntu downloads NEVER match

Tags: 14.04, downloads, hash, checksums

I have tried to download the 14.04.1 and 14.04 versions of Ubuntu serveral times from different mirrors on different PCs/Laptops using Firefox to download from the site and BitTorrent to download via P2P and i **always** get the **same** MD5 hash (the 14.04 version generates another one ofcourse), which is different from the ones in the MD5SUMS document (http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/MD5SUMS).

What I get (14.04.1):
**72035AA8DD9DEDF9685983F27AE747D1**

What the original sums are (14.04.1):
**119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd**

The files ARE corrupted and cause problems while booting from USB/DVD.

Any idea where the problem comes from?
I have an otherwise stable internet connection and I can download just about everything without corruption but I cannot get any Linux to work right now.
I also tried fedora yesterday and those downloads had mismatches, too.

Answer (score 0):

Linux iso files are pretty large; so an issue that may not affect a small file may corrupt the larger iso file. A torrent client should correctly download the iso and discard anything that gets corrupted.

Go to the alternate downloads on Ubuntu.com and download the .torrent file. It will open up in Transmission on Ubuntu and begin downloading the iso. Transmission verifies each piece it downloads, but if you want to be extra sure you can still check the MD5 from the terminal with `md5sum ~/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` after it finishes downloading and compare it to the hash here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

If you think your connection is the issue you can test for packet loss with http://www.pingtest.net/ . You will need to have the java plug-in for Firefox. Contact your ISP if you think things are not working correctly. They can come to your place and test the line to the ISP and fix signal loss issues.

Comment: Ill try Transmission tomorrow and report how it worked.
I do not think that my ISP/internet connection is at fault.
I never had any package loss before.

Comment: I took the time and did it this evening.
I still get the same MD5 hash ... i dont think a error due to data corruption while downloading etc can be possible since the hash is always the same.